# Why does an analog chip have two ground connections but not two vcc connections?

Tags: power, analog

I'll be using an TLC7528 dual DAC IC in my circuit, and it has two pins for ground named AGND and DGND (which to me means analog and digital ground). It only has one pin VDD for power. Why would it only have one pin for power and two for ground? Why don't they make them so I get the AVDD and DVDD and GND pins instead?

Comment: Your premise (It only has one pin VDD for power.) is flawed. Each resistor ladder is actually independently powered through REFA and REFB.  As observed by @Peter Smith.

Comment: @Mike can you visualize Analog Ground shift from Logic Noise? I have seen this in my 1st ADC/DAC system design using Burr Brown Hybrid 12MHz ADC's in the mid 70's , It still occurs everywhere but to a smaller extent. Most people never measure it.   It affects Monotonicity. If you can't imagine logic noise crosstalk on AG (gnd) or visualize it yet.  It shifts the Vref.    I think it's important to know how to test/measure/detect it.  I'll simulate it for you if anyone likes.

Answer (score 2):

The different GNDs are not for powering the different parts of the chip, but for providing different 0V reference points for the chips operation.

This way the digital operation of the chip can have wildly varying current flow out through DGND without affecting a rock solid (if you did your PCB layout properly) AGND 0V reference.

Comment: So this means I can connect DGND directly to the battery negative terminal and make some sort of inverted pi filter where the input is battery ground (DGND) and output is AGND?

Comment: @Mike: I suggest you google about the term "star grounding". In short: you provide independent low impedance paths to a central gnd point. No fancy filtering needed. Make sure your vcc is properly decoupled

Comment: I actually did research that but its difficult to achieve that in a complex circuit

Comment: @Mike: this is why people study that stuff and there is active research. Try reading some questions on this site and build a prototype, measure it, and if doesn't perform you may be able to ask here about recommendations for improvement

Answer (score 2):

I will convert my comment to an answer:

The actual power paths are in the datasheet:

The DAC ladders actually have their own power domain (they share analogue ground):

[image: TLC7528 DAC ladder power]

That means that the power paths for the entire device is this:

[image: TLC7528 power paths]

The analogue power path is in green.

Answer (score 1):

If you only had one ground connection, all the currents taken by the digital IO pins would flood into the chip and impregnate the analogue circuit grounds causing noise on those circuits and the chip would not achieve the performance levels it claims. It has nothing to do with trying to match the number of supply pins with ground pins.

A separate ground for the analogue allows a single point connection to digital ground and therefore digital currents cannot enter the localized analogue ground.

Comment: But why no separate Vdd pins? Is supply impedance assumed to be significantly lower than GND's?

Comment: Voltage Vdd mainly supplies the digital stuff and what regulates or controls the analogue voltages is the Vref voltage so, if you want to look at this way, you could argue that there are two supply voltages with Vref being the important analogue supply.

Comment: It is true that impedance on both the return (GND) and supply (VDD) side could theoretically cause noise in one part of the chip (the digital part, for example) to couple into another, more sensitive part of the chip. However, chips are usually designed with some inherent immunity to supply noise. This comes about because sensitive signals like reference voltages are usually bypassed to ground rather than VDD, because blocks often have sub-regulators that reduce supply noise with respect to GND, because the IC substrate is usually connected to GND, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the equivalent internal circuit, you will see that the actual D/A resistor ladder is switched using Agnd so the the output signal will be free from any digital noise on the Dgnd node.

It is easier to filter voltage on the power pin than current on the ground pin.

If you want a DAC with SEPARATE power for digital and analog, then you need to select a different chip. There are hundreds to chose from.

Comment: The DAC resistor ladder is powered from the REFA/B supplies, not Vdd, so the analogue section has its own power domain.

Comment: @Peter Smith you are absolutely correct.  And that makes the original question flawed stating that "It only has one pin VDD for power. "  So the premise for the question is incorrect.